# hide the div when scroll down the remaining 100px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide my **div**, when scrolling down the remaining 100px.
If you have any answer please help me

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 2300) {
    $('.bottomMenu').show();
  } else if { ?
  } else {
    $('.bottomMenu').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.bottomMenu {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bottomMenu" style="background:red; height:100px;width:100px;">ikanbakar</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the full code in a fiddle ??

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle that is working?

Comment: what you mean by `remaining 100px`

Comment: @SunilHari No. Please do not ask full code. Just ask for enough code that is required to simulate.

Comment: @Rajesh:Thats what i meant.Just enough to solve this problem he is facing

Comment: @SunilHari People might take your words seriously and dump all their code. So its better to be specific.

Comment: @Rajesh:I hope they will read these comments

Comment: wait, i can try upload my file

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/557zcn0u/13/

Answer (score 0):

This should be the code. you should add a class in css as

> bottomMenu.active{}

to define your styles there.

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 2300) {
        $(".bottomMenu").addClass("active");
    } else {
       $(".bottomMenu").removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your help but i just want to hide or remove the class when 100px left bottom. do you have the answer?

Answer (score 0):

well if you want this here is the example hope it can help you

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() < 300) {
    //you have to change the value according to your content
        $(".bottomMenu").addClass("game");
    } else {
       $(".bottomMenu").removeClass("game");
    }
});
```

```css
.bottomMenu{display:none;}
.game {
  display:block;
position: fixed;
top: 10%;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
border-top: 1px solid #000;
background: red;}

.nav {
  font-weight: normal;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  background-color: #4F4F4F;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
}

.nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  color: #c1c1c1;
}

.footer {
float:left;

  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

.footer li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.footer li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}
header {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}


.footer {
    background: #333;
}
body{ margin:0px auto;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
<section style="float:left;width:100%;">
<p>    Ensure growth and profitability by extending our product portfolio in other categories of HPC business in domestic and international markets.
    Continuously improve our system and products to enhance customer satisfaction.
    Continue with our commitment to operate business in an ethical manner.
    Develop & motivate ZIL people to build a high performance culture.
    Deliver high quality branded and innovative products and services to ensure customer satisfaction.
    Simplify business processes and reduce complexity to achieve business growth.
    Optimize resources to ensure competitiveness.
    Ensure regulatory and statutory compliance and embed best practices of corporate governance.</p>
    <div class="bottomMenu game" style="background:red; height:100px;width:100px;">ikanbakar</div>
    <p>    Ensure growth and profitability by extending our product portfolio in other categories of HPC business in domestic and international markets.
    Continuously improve our system and products to enhance customer satisfaction.
    Continue with our commitment to operate business in an ethical manner.
    Develop & motivate ZIL people to build a high performance culture.
    Deliver high quality branded and innovative products and services to ensure customer satisfaction.
    Simplify business processes and reduce complexity to achieve business growth.
    Optimize resources to ensure competitiveness.
    Ensure regulatory and statutory compliance and embed best practices of corporate governance.</p>

</section>
<footer>
  <ul class="footer">
    <li><a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/wow">Made by Lumo © 2017</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Comment: thank you for your help but i just want to hide or remove the class when 100px left bottom. do you have the answer?

Comment: can you please elaborate you want div to hide when you reach bottom..??? or when you reach bottom it shows and when you scroll up it hide..???

Comment: My wish is : 
if (y > 2300) = show ; 
else if ( scrooll bottom remaining 100) = hide ;

Comment: @safagroup you can check it now brother

Answer (score 0):

can you try this ?

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    if(($(document).height() - $(document).scrollTop()) > 100 ) {
       $('.bottomMenu').show();
    } else {
       $('.bottomMenu').hide();
    }
});
```

or javascript way like

```
document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.scrollTop
```

Comment: Can you give `$(document).scroll(function () { console.log($(document).height() - $(document).scrollTop()) })` and get me what you are getting in console while scrolling

Comment: My wish is : 
if (y > 2300) = show ; 
else if ( scrooll bottom remaining 100) = hide ;

Comment: if you are searching for how to write condition for ` scroll bottom remaining 100`  then `($(this).height() - y)  <= 100` will do I guess